# wit.ai integration issue with facebook messenger

Tags: facebook, webhooks, chatbot, facebook-messenger, wit.ai

I integrated wit.ai with facebook messenger. Its working good with my fb account? But if I try with others account, webhook call is not called. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you using your own app id? And if so, is it in live mode, and did you get all the necessary features/permissions reviewed already?

Comment: I resolved this issue. I have to send the app for review. So the application will be available to all the users. We can also add test users to test the app. Test users can test app without review.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. I have to send the app for review to Facebook. So the application will be available to all the users. We can also add test users to test the app. Test users can test app without review.